# Show HTML tags in XML

Tags: html, xml, tags, xhtml

If I want to show:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

tags in HTML, how can I register this as Data instead of HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap them in a [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect) section:

```
<some_xml_element>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Where is<br/>pancakes house?</p>
    ]]>
</some_xml_element>
```

Answer (score 2):

... or escaping special characters:

```
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give either HTML tags or your XML markup a differrent namespace. You'll have to write something like `<foo>...<h:html>...</h:html>...</foo>`.

If you don't need to *parse* the HTML tags, you can just put the whole thing inside a [`<![CDATA[...]]>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).